# Race or deadlock in client-server with tcp/ip sockets

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking, java.util.concurrent

I am working on a simple Java client-server game. Both server and client run multiple threads concurrently.
On the server there are two concurrent tasks (callable run on multiple threads) who are randomly fighting with each other. Sooner or later, after a client connects to a server, they block each other (dont know maybe deadlock, maybe race) and whole connections freeze.
I checked many related topics here, tried many modifications, many changes of design and logic, both in client and the server. Unfortunately didnt managed to solve it yet.
If you need any other classes feel free to ask.
Any help is much appreciated.

Below are this two blocking task classes (server side).

```
public class ClientUpdateTask extends AbstractClientTask {

private final String location = "update task execute";

public ClientUpdateTask(String clientToken, ServerManager serverManager, 
        ReadWriteLock clientTaskLock) {
    super(clientToken, serverManager, GameConditions.UPDATE_TASK, clientTaskLock);
}

@Override
public Boolean call() throws /*Exception*/ IOException {
    if(clientTaskLock.readLock().tryLock()) {
    try {
        execute();
        return true;
    } catch(IOException e) {
        String exLocation = "update task execute ioex";
        ClientDisconnectedException cde = new ClientDisconnectedException(
                clientToken, exLocation, e.getMessage(), e);
        error = cde;
        throw cde;
        //throw new RuntimeException("ex updating clients", e);
        //throw e;
    } finally {clientTaskLock.readLock().unlock();}
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void execute() throws IOException {
    if(!serverManager.areAtleastTwoConnected())
        return;
    Client client = serverManager.getClient(clientToken, location);
    String clientAddress = client.getSocket().getRemoteSocketAddress().toString();
    client.printLine(GameConditions.SERVER_MODE_SEND);
    String inSerEntsLenTxt = client.readLine();
    printClientPacket(clientAddress, "after 1st readl, ents len: "+inSerEntsLenTxt);
    if(inSerEntsLenTxt != null && !(inSerEntsLenTxt.isEmpty())) {
        int inSerEntsLen = Integer.parseInt(inSerEntsLenTxt);
        inStreamBuff = new char[inSerEntsLen];
        inStreamBuff = client.readCharsToArray(inStreamBuff, 0, inSerEntsLen);
        String inSerEnts = new String(inStreamBuff);
        printClientPacket(clientAddress, "in ser ents: "+inSerEnts);
        //List<Client> clients = serverManager.getClients();
        if(clientTaskLock.writeLock().tryLock()) {
        try {
        for(Client clientOther : serverManager.getClients()) {
            String clientOtherToken = clientOther.getToken();
            if(!clientOtherToken.equals(clientToken)) {
                clientOther.printLine(GameConditions.SERVER_MODE_RECEIVE);
                clientOther.printLine(inSerEntsLen);
                clientOther.writeChars(inSerEnts);
            }
        }
        } finally {clientTaskLock.writeLock().unlock();}
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
public class ClientHeartbeatTask extends AbstractClientTask {

private final String location = "heartbeat task execute";

public ClientHeartbeatTask(String clientToken, ServerManager serverManager,
        ReadWriteLock clientTaskLock) {
    super(clientToken, serverManager, GameConditions.HEARTBEAT_TASK, clientTaskLock);
}

@Override
public Boolean call() throws /*Exception*/ IOException {
    if(clientTaskLock.readLock().tryLock()) {
    try {
        execute();
        return true;
    } catch(IOException e) {
        String exLocation = "heartbeat task execute ioex";
        ClientDisconnectedException cde = new ClientDisconnectedException(
                clientToken, exLocation, e.getMessage(), e);
        error = cde;
        throw cde;
        //throw new RuntimeException("ex listening client heartbeat", e);
        //throw e;
    } finally {clientTaskLock.readLock().unlock();}
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void execute() throws IOException {
    Client client = serverManager.getClient(clientToken, location);
    String clientAddress = client.getSocket().getRemoteSocketAddress().toString();
    String inToken = "";
    //System.out.println("listening...");
    client.printLine(GameConditions.SERVER_MODE_HEARTBEAT); //1
    client.printLine(clientToken);
    inToken = client.readLine(); //2
    if(inToken != null) {
        Matcher tokenMatcher = GameConditions.TOKEN_PATTERN.matcher(inToken);
        //System.out.println("in token not null");
        if(tokenMatcher.matches()) {
            printClientPacket(clientAddress, "after 1st readl, token matched: " + inToken);
            serverManager.updateClient(clientToken, location);
        }
    } else {
        long idle = (long) (System.currentTimeMillis() - client.getLastHeartBeat());
        //System.out.println("idle: " + idle);
        if(idle > GameConditions.CLIENT_MAX_IDLE_TIME) {
            serverManager.disconnectClient(clientToken);
            throw new IOException("client disconnected, throw to "
                + "close resources and stop thread");
        }
    }
}
```

}

**EDIT**
Donno if its impoortant to say but the best i managed to do so far, was that client side tasks (who comunicate with this two) receives messages from server (until this figthing starts). But server is silennt, no messages received.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to post solution so here it is.
Removed direct input / output stream access from update and heartbeat tasks.
They both run on multiple threads in both client and server and believe 
it was the reason for blocking of threads and whole communication.
Instead moved direct stream access to separate class (Client), who has two ArrayBlockingQueues 
and provides thread safe interface for sockets' stream reading and writing.
All incoming messages are added to input queue, and all outgoing messages are added to output queue.
Now Created two more tasks both in client and server, one who reads to input queue, and one who writes from output queue.
And also during the proccess, big bunch of my synchronizations and locks turned out to be useless (and probably could also block threads, and definitely slowed performance).

Changed update task:

```
public class ClientUpdateTask extends AbstractClientTask {

    private final String location = "update task execute";

    public ClientUpdateTask(String clientToken, ServerManager serverManager, 
            ReadWriteLock clientTaskLock) {
        super(clientToken, serverManager, GameConditions.UPDATE_TASK, clientTaskLock);
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws /*Exception*/ IOException {
        try {
            execute();
            return true;
        } catch(IOException e) {
            String exLocation = "update task execute ioex";
            ClientDisconnectedException cde = new ClientDisconnectedException(
                    clientToken, exLocation, e.getMessage(), e);
            error = cde;
            throw cde;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void execute() throws IOException {
        if(!serverManager.areAtleastTwoConnected())
            return;
        Client client = serverManager.getClient(clientToken, location);
        String clientAddress = client.getSocket().getRemoteSocketAddress().toString();
        String inMessage = client.peekInMessage();
        if(inMessage != null && !inMessage.isEmpty() && 
                inMessage.startsWith(GameConditions.SERVER_MODE_SEND)) {
            client.pollInMessage();
            String[] inMessageSplitArray = inMessage.split(
                    GameConditions.MESSAGE_FRAGMENT_SEPARATOR);
            String inSerEnts = inMessageSplitArray[1];
            for(Client clientOther : serverManager.getClients()) {
                String clientOtherToken = clientOther.getToken();
                if(!clientOtherToken.equals(clientToken)) {
                    String outMessage = GameConditions.SERVER_MODE_RECEIVE
                        + GameConditions.MESSAGE_FRAGMENT_SEPARATOR + inSerEnts;
                    clientOther.pushOutMessage(outMessage);
                }
            }
        }
        String outMessage = GameConditions.SERVER_MODE_SEND;
        client.pushOutMessage(outMessage);
    }
}
```

Changed heartbeat task:

```
public class ClientHeartbeatTask extends AbstractClientTask {

    private final String location = "heartbeat task execute";

    public ClientHeartbeatTask(String clientToken, ServerManager serverManager,
            ReadWriteLock clientTaskLock) {
        super(clientToken, serverManager, GameConditions.HEARTBEAT_TASK, clientTaskLock);
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws /*Exception*/ IOException {
        try {
            execute();
            return true;
        } catch(IOException e) {
            String exLocation = "heartbeat task execute ioex";
            ClientDisconnectedException cde = new ClientDisconnectedException(
                    clientToken, exLocation, e.getMessage(), e);
            error = cde;
            throw cde;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void execute() throws IOException {
        Client client = serverManager.getClient(clientToken, location);
        String clientAddress = client.getSocket().getRemoteSocketAddress().toString();
        String inMessage = client.peekInMessage(); //2
        if(inMessage != null && !inMessage.isEmpty() && 
                inMessage.startsWith(GameConditions.SERVER_MODE_HEARTBEAT)) {
            client.pollInMessage();
            String[] inMessageSplitArray = inMessage.split(
                    GameConditions.MESSAGE_FRAGMENT_SEPARATOR);
            String inToken = inMessageSplitArray[1];
            Matcher tokenMatcher = GameConditions.TOKEN_PATTERN.matcher(inToken);
        }
        String outMessage = GameConditions.SERVER_MODE_HEARTBEAT + 
            GameConditions.MESSAGE_FRAGMENT_SEPARATOR + clientToken;
        client.pushOutMessage(outMessage);
        long idle = (long) (System.currentTimeMillis() - client.getLastHeartBeat());
        if(idle > GameConditions.CLIENT_MAX_IDLE_TIME) {
            System.out.println("client idle time expired");
            serverManager.disconnectClient(clientToken);
            throw new IOException("client disconnected, throw to "
                + "close resources and stop thread");
        }
    }

}
```

New input reader task:

```
public class ClientInputListenerTask extends AbstractClientTask {

    private final String location = "input listener task execute";

    public ClientInputListenerTask(String clientToken, ServerManager serverManager, 
            ReadWriteLock clientTaskLock) {
        super(clientToken, serverManager, GameConditions.UPDATE_TASK, clientTaskLock);
    }

    @Override
    protected void execute() throws IOException {
        Client client = serverManager.getClient(clientToken, location);
        String inputLine = client.readLine();
        if(inputLine != null && !inputLine.isEmpty()) {
            client.pushInMessage(inputLine);
            System.out.println(client.getToken()+", in message: "+inputLine
                +", last heartbeat: "+client.getLastHeartBeat());
            serverManager.updateClient(client.getToken(), location);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        try {
            execute();
            return true;
        } catch(IOException e) {
            String exLocation = "input listener task execute ioex";
            ClientDisconnectedException cde = new ClientDisconnectedException(
                    clientToken, exLocation, e.getMessage(), e);
            error = cde;
            throw cde;
        }
    }
}
```

New output writer task:

```
public class ClientOutputPrinterTask extends AbstractClientTask {

    private final String location = "input listener task execute";

    public ClientOutputPrinterTask(String clientToken, ServerManager serverManager, 
            ReadWriteLock clientTaskLock) {
        super(clientToken, serverManager, GameConditions.UPDATE_TASK, clientTaskLock);
    }

    @Override
    protected void execute() throws IOException {
        Client client = serverManager.getClient(clientToken, location);
        String outputLine = client.pollOutMessage();
        if(outputLine != null)
            client.printLine(outputLine);
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        try {
            execute();
            return true;
        } catch(IOException e) {
            String exLocation = "input listener task execute ioex";
            ClientDisconnectedException cde = new ClientDisconnectedException(
                    clientToken, exLocation, e.getMessage(), e);
            error = cde;
            throw cde;
        }
    }
}
```